# Access to methods which is in another classlibrary,HOW?

Tags: c#

I have a smple Question:

How can I access to a class and its Methods in another class library from my class?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to add a reference to the library. Then you should be able to access by using

```
MyLibrary.MyClass.MyMethod();
```

Answer (score 2):

Suppose you have static mathed on public class of libarary in name space MyNamespace then

```
MyNamespace.MyPublicClass.MyStaticMethod();
```

If You have class with public method then you can access it

```
new MyNamespace.MyPublicClass().MyStaticMethod();
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the library to your class.

Then you should be able to call the methods.

So for example at the top of your class you would write:

```
  using mylibrary.library;
```

Then you should have access to your methods in the same way you would access other methods.